# How do I upload/index rich/structured text documents to search with ElasticSearch?

Tags: solr, indexing, elasticsearch, information-retrieval, structured-data

I am building a search engine around a corpus of documents including Microsoft Word Docs, PowerPoints, PDFs, and text files. I have successfully downloaded and installed ElasticSearch and have it running (visible from the command prompt and from a browser - localhost:9200).

I can upload and search data that is entered manually (found in several tutorials online - such as this one: http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/elasticsearch-in-5-minutes.html#Indexing)

Now I need to make the (large?) jump from searching manually entered data to searching the large corpus of structured text files. My question is - how do I go about uploading/indexing these documents to make them available to the Elasticsearch instance I am already running.

I understand this may be too large to answer in a single reply - even being pointed to a tool or tutorial link would help.

Versions: Windows 7, Elasticsearch 1.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try using the Elasticsearch attachment plugin:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-attachment-type.html
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments

> Attachment Type
>
> The attachment type allows to index different "attachment" type field
>   (encoded as base64), for example, Microsoft Office formats, open
>   document formats, ePub, HTML, and so on (full list can be found here).
>
> The attachment type is provided as a plugin extension. The plugin is a
>   simple zip file that can be downloaded and placed under
>   $ES_HOME/plugins location. It will be automatically detected and the
>   attachment type will be added.

It's built using Apache Tika and supports the following file formats:

> Supported Document Formats
>
> - HyperText Markup Language
> - XML and derived formats
> - Microsoft Office document formats
> - OpenDocument Format
> - Portable Document Format
> - Electronic Publication Format
> - Rich Text Format
> - Compression and packaging formats
> - Text formats
> - Audio formats
> - Image formats
> - Video formats
> - Java class files and archives
> - The mbox format

http://tika.apache.org/0.10/formats.html

It's provided as a plugin - if you're not familiar with the plugin architecture I'd take a look here:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html

Comment: This is definitely the direction I was looking to be pointed in, thank you. I'll give it a shot.